# What techniques should be employed to optimise @font-face rendering?

Tags: css, optimization, font-face

I'm using the @font-face rule quite a bit; much more than I did, say, 6 months ago.

Given that different browsers handle the @font-face rule in different ways, what approaches and considerations do I need to keep foremost in mind to optimise performance across different browsers and devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you should read [this post](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/04/05/lessons-on-font-face-from-the-f2e-summit/) from Nicholas Zakas.